# Access Static member

Tags: c#

I know that we can access Static member just with class name like this

```
Myclass.MyStaticMember
```

and no need to initialize this

but my question is why we cant access Static member from initialize object

```
Myclass.MyStaticMember obj =new  Myclass.MyStaticMember()
obj.MyStaticMember
```

is there related via `CLR` or .net framework architecture  or compiler

Comment: A static member variable *cannot* be a member of an instance of an object. It is shared among all instances of the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a language decision, to make your code clearer. (It would have been entirely *feasible* for the C# compiler to compile the code into a static access based on the compile-time type of the variable.) If you write:

```
obj.StaticMember
```

it *looks* like the member is specific to `obj` - but it's not. Code shouldn't lie.

As an example of how confusing this can be, consider the following valid Java code (assuming a `Runnable` variable called `runnable`):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
thread.start();
thread.sleep(1000);
```

Which thread does that send to sleep? The new one, of course - look, it's calling `sleep()` on the variable referring to the new thread. Except of course `Thread.sleep` is a static method, which *always* makes the currently executing thread sleep. That's not **at all** obvious from the code above. Fortunately, it wouldn't be valid in C#.

This is one area where the C# team apparently learned from Java's mistakes, which I'm jolly glad about. (Shame about some of the other aspects, but hey...)

Comment: +1 for describing *why* it's generally done this way, since it fairly equally applies to all languages.

Comment: @ShahroozJefri: Read the specification in detail. It's very well written.

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you have any resource?I love c# and I WANT and WANT learn like you.thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The static member "does not belong" to any given instance of a `Type T` - it belongs *to the type itself*, in one sense.

The actual "values" are associated with the corresponding `EEClass` deep down in the CLR details, which is shared across all instances of that type.